# Custom bean validation with tow types using ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, annotations, annotation-processing

I am following this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

I am facing now a situation where i have two different types, one of them is `List<String>` and the other one is in other different class is of type `Set<String>`

And i want to check the validation of the string elements inside of them using regex. `^[a-z0-9]+[-_]*[a-z0-9]*$`

So instead of having two bean validation annotation one is with `List<String>`

```
implements 
  ConstraintValidator<ContactNumberConstraint, List<String>>
```

and the other one is with `Set<String>`

```
implements 
  ConstraintValidator<ContactNumberConstraint, Set<String>>
```

Is it possible to have one class accepting both types? If yes a code snippet will be very helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `List` and `Set` are `Collection`s and you don't care about specifics of its implementations (you only intend to iterate through elements and validate them) you could simply use `implements ConstraintValidator<ContactNumberConstraint, Collection<String>>`